# Where can I find the specifications of the Wire Protocol used by Oracle database server?

Tags: oracle

I want to write my own Oracle ODBC driver, and wanted to know if the specifications of the Client Driver are published somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

To write an oracle odbc driver all you'd need is to follow the instructions here -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714629(v=VS.85).aspx

I may be misunderstanding the question though - I'm not sure why you'd need the wire protocol - for oracle this would be sqlnet.

hth

Comment: To implement the driver, akshat will need the specification of the wire protocol.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I perhaps didn't think it through - I thought initially that you could just use oci to bind to, but then of course you'll need the oracle client installed. So you'd then need to write a sql*net client which is notoriously undocumented. is there any other way? - just curious.

Comment: you are right: binding to OCI should work (and that's probably what the "original" Oracle driver is doing as well). Writing a sql*net client should be possible as the JDBC driver does not require any client software to be installed as well. But the sources for the JDBC driver are not available.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - you are right, I need the actual and the link in the answer will not work. Any ideas, where I may find it?

Comment: @akshat: other than decompiling the JDBC driver, no.